# I keep getting NoSuchElement Exception with Scanner's in.nextXXXX

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I don't know what's happening. I've used `Scanner` for input plenty of times in the past and never had any chronic issue. Now no matter what I do I keep getting `NoSuchElementException` every time I ask for user input. I've checked the previous answers and they don't help (mostly they seem to suggest using a while for `hasnextXXXX` but this effectively does nothing because instead of an exception my code just doesn't do anything).

Below is the error and my code (latest iteration, before calling it in a setter I was calling it in the constructor, always the same exception). What is going on?! Please Help!!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Character.setAttack(Character.java:24)
    at Character.setAll(Character.java:15)
    at Fight.main(Fight.java:25)
```

---

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Character {

        private int attack;
        private Scanner in;

        public Character() {

            in = new Scanner(System.in);
        }

        public void setAll() {
            setAttack(0);
        }

        public int getAttack() {
            return attack;
        }

        public void setAttack(int attack) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            attack = scan.nextInt();
            this.attack = attack;
            System.out.println("character// attack is " + attack);//test
        }

    }
```

Comment: You cannot bind the System.in multiple times as far as i concern

Comment: In `setAttack()` you create a new `Scanner` on each call.  Why? You already have a `Scanner` bound to `System.in` as a member variable named `in`. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: Also, when the system pauses for you to type something, what are you typing?

Comment: sorry that was just sloppy coding, i was going through so many iterations trying to get something to work that i forgot to take one of those off. the exception still throws with only one .in bound. EDIT: originally i had one scanner creation, the one in the method was me flailing because nothing seems to work.

Comment: i typed in a selection in my main. do i need to clear that selction first, somehow?

Comment: Please edit to reflect the better, yet still failing, code.

Comment: I was able to fix(or more accurately, make stop) the error. I didn't think to link my main method. But I had a bunch of static methods in there all doing stuff with scanner. I think that's what messed it up. As they say, 'only use main to initialize your program'. Sorry about the confusion. Thank you all for helping though! It was these comments that helped the light bulb come on for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you **remove the second Scanner initiation** and fix `setAttack()` method to the following:

```
public void setAttack(int attack) {
         attack = in.nextInt();
         this.attack = attack;
         System.out.println("character// attack is "+attack);//test
    }
```

... and input an `int` to console, everything will work.